How to only allow a boolean to be true if another boolean in the same row is true in MariaDB?
I have two boolean columns in my table. One called IsUnlisted and one called IsPrivate. I only want to allow IsPrivate to be 1 (TRUE) if IsUnlisted is 1 (TRUE) as well using a check constraint. I am using MariaDB which shares most things with mysql.

Please don't assume MariaDB and MySQL are compatible products. A solution for one may not work on the other. Treat them as different products, as you would MariaDB and for example Oracle.

Bill Karwin I know, but a lot of the syntax is similar, and if somebody knows MySQL they can probably help out. Worse case is it doesn't work.

ENUM state ('neither, 'isPrivate', 'isUnlisted')

The booleans give you 4 states; the above gives you only 3.

That is probably the best approach actually, I would just change neither to public for my use case

CREATE TABLE test (
  IsUnlisted BOOLEAN,
  IsPrivate BOOLEAN,
  CHECK (IsUnlisted <> TRUE OR IsPrivate <=> TRUE)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO test VALUES
(NULL, NULL),
(NULL, TRUE),
(NULL, FALSE),
(TRUE, NULL),    -- illegal
(TRUE, TRUE),
(TRUE, FALSE),   -- illegal
(FALSE, NULL),
(FALSE, TRUE),
(FALSE, FALSE);

SHOW WARNINGS;




Level
Code
Message




Warning
4025
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `fiddle`.`test`


Warning
4025
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `fiddle`.`test`



SELECT * FROM test;




IsUnlisted
IsPrivate




null
null


null
1


null
0


1
1


0
null


0
1


0
0



fiddle
The row is inserted if CHECK constraint expression is TRUE or NULL.
If IsUnlisted <> TRUE is TRUE or NULL (i.e. IsUnlisted is NULL or FALSE) then CHECK expression is TRUE or NULL accordingly, and the row is valid.
If IsUnlisted <> TRUE is FALSE (i.e. IsUnlisted is TRUE) then IsPrivate <=> TRUE is checked. It is TRUE only when IsPrivate is TRUE, and it is FALSE if IsPrivate is NULL or FALSE.
The insertion of the rows which does not match the CHECK constraint produces warnings.

There is no possibility for it to be null, because I have a not null constraint (I forgot to mention) I only want an error when IsUnlisted is false and IsPrivate is true.

@Garbg If so then something like CHECK (IsUnlisted = FALSE OR IsPrivate = TRUE) is enough.
